# eclipse link jpa sequence jump

Tags: jpa, oracle11g, eclipselink

```
create sequence SUBMISSION_SEQ
  start with 1
  INCREMENT BY 1;



@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBMISSION")
public class Submission { 
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "submission_seq_gen") 
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "submission_seq_gen", sequenceName = "SUBMISSION_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1) 
    @Column(name = "SUBMISSION_ID")
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Sequence number jumps sometimes directly by 10-12, sometimes it increases correctly by 1 that i intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequences are not meant to be densely sequential. That's just a fact. The best possible solution to your issue is: To forget about it. Sequence-generated IDs are nothing more than meaniningless pointers, object identifiers, to be used for table row referencing.

If you need a dense sequential numbering (for whatever reason it may be), you'll have to implement it yourself as a separate column in your table.

Anyway, it may be the case that you're dealing here with the default caching of a sequence. If you want, try setting up your sequence as follows:

```
create sequence SUBMISSION_SEQ
  start with 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  nocache;
```

but please be aware that for large amounts of data this **will** harm performance of the data insertions.